# Is this a type of recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion

Consider a series of integers $a$ defined by:

$$\begin{cases}
a_n      & = c_n             & \text{if $0 \le n \le 2$} \\
a_{2n}   & = f(a_n, a_{n+1}) & \text{if $n > 1$}   \quad \text{(even $n$)} \\
a_{2n+1} & = g(a_{n-1}, a_n) & \text{if $n \ge 1$} \quad \text{(odd $n$)}
\end{cases}$$

where $c_0, c_1, c_2$ are constants.  The subscript of the second and third cases is meant to convey multiplication (e.g. for $n=5,\enspace a_{10} = f(a_4, a_5)$).

It seems very similar to a recurrence relation, as latter terms are defined as a function of previous terms, except for the fact that the series isn't defined sequentially.

Note that for $a_6$ depends on terms $a_3$ and $a_4$ -- 3 and 2 terms "away", respectively -- while $a_{100}$ depends on terms $a_{50}$ and $a_{51}$.

Is this still a recurrence relation?  If not (or if so, I suppose) is there a better name for this construction so I can get more information on how to approach generalizing it (i.e. calculating an arbitrary term without needing to generate the entire sequence).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a recurrence relation.

Comment: Also no, there is no general method for solving recurrence relations. Many of them can't be solved with today's methods.

Comment: ... but a recurrence with such a structure gives an efficient way for computing Fibonacci or Lucas numbers, for instance.